# System Login using PHP connected to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm updating this question because after 2 months, I still can't solve the problem of creating sign-in into the system. I have followed the tutorial at [php sql server manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) but my login is still didn't work.

Following is my code

db.php

```html
<?php
date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
// $serverName = "PPT-PR1"; //serverName\instanceName
$serverName = "10.14.29.111"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DEV_SPOT", "UID"=>"spot.assist", "PWD"=>"Admin123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
}else{
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


?>
```

and here is the index page hosting the login form

```html
<form method="post" action="login.php">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="true">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->

  </div>
</form>
```

and finally, this is the login.php script that I made as simple as I can

```html
<?php

    include ('db.php');

    session_start();

    echo $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM [DEV_SPOT].[dbo].[SPOT_User] WHERE username='$username' AND PASSWORD='$password'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
 $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);


if($stmt == true){

        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];


        header("Location: user/index.php");
    }
    else
        echo '<script> alert("Wrong Username And Password");
                    </script>'
?>
```

The problem right now, after I click on sign in button, I stay on the index.php page without any prompt of error. I hope someone can help me to find where did I do wrong in this code. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP PDO database connector  https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I agree with Richard.. But if you insist on using "sqlsrv", then try adding `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` (Replace 55 with version) to your extension list in php.ini... Seems like the extension isn't activated :)

Comment: I see..thank you for telling me